# Inconsistent crashes at random places in an application on Windows 10

Tags: c

I have been developing an application for many years and it has been working well on Windows 10 compiled with Open Watcom.  All it does is read a text file and produce a number of html files. Within the past months it has been crashing at random times about 10-20% of the time with the same input data. When it’s compiled by gcc on the Mac/OS X, it works fine and does not crash on the Mac. I backed off on mnay of the recent changes I made to the code but do not wish to undo my work unnecessarily. Debuggers and dignostic output do not seem useful as the results of the crashes seem random and inconsistent. I can run the same input data several times and get failures in different places with different crash maps produced that all start something like the following:

```
The instruction at 0x0042e973 referenced memory at 0x006e8f2d.
The memory could not be read.
Exception fielded by 0x0042dcb0
EAX=0x00000001 EBX=0xffffff43 ECX=0x0042002b EDX=0x00458f2d
```

Any help to diagnose this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the *undefined behaviour* in your code has always been there but has not caused any bad effects. It can happen that changing an unrelated part of the code exposes that, and it is not easy to find. Or, the bug was recently introduced. One thing now in your favour is that although the *result* seems inconsistent, if it is *frequent* that allows you to employ a "divide & conquer" approach.

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean there's no bugs. Use tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to spot potential errors. Turn on *all* compiler warnings. When posting on Stack Overflow don't come to us with "my program has a bug", that doesn't communicate anything useful, instead *show us the code* so we can help.

Comment: Did you try to get back to your source with the addresses printed? What does you compiler/debugger manual say about this? Did you follow the chain of calls when your program crashed in the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I did go back to older code but the inconsistent crashes persisted. After a cleanup with sfc /scannow, the problem almost disappeared. I was ready to bring in the debugger to finish it off but an upgrade of my IDE did it first. I have the feeling that the problem could easily re-appear but I will be ready to deal with it

Answer (score 1):

In such a case, the most useful thing is a memory dump or even a crash dump, which contains the call stack of the thing the computer was trying to do when it crashed.

There are two ways ahead for this:

- Either you alter your application in such a way that, when it crashes, a crash or memory dump is created automatically.
- Either the user of the application configures his system in such a way that an application, which crashes, causes a crash dump or memory dump to be created.

Choose wisely :-)